# Android unable to escaping single quote character while SQLite database update

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi in my database i have a string like "computer's" , i am fetching it from database and displaying listview, when i click on the list item it should store to one of my database table. I am doing it as below but it is getting crashed

```
public void updateFav(String key, int value) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        C_FAV=C_FAV.replaceAll("'","''");
        values.put(C_FAV, value);
        db.update(tableName, values, C_KEY + "='" + key.trim() + "'", null);
        db.close();
    }
```

Below is my trace

```
12-12 17:55:49.291: E/AndroidRuntime(18184): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": 
syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE fav SET favorite=? WHERE key='computer's'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're escaping the apostrophes in `C_FAV` which seems to be a column name but not in `key`.

Consider using `?` placeholder and bind arguments instead, e.g.

```
db.update(tableName, values, C_KEY + "=?", new String[] { key.trim() });
```

Comment: @laalto...That's exactly what i want, i should be doing for C_KEY using the ? placeholder..thank you